# RoR application takes long time to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boot

I have RoR application and it takes long time to start for first time. About 5-10 min.
Link to my app - [HERE](http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/)

But when it starts it works quite good. Some off my server adminstrators sugested that **I have to use  cron to curl the front page every 30 minutes or so.**

That could be the solution ?
Or how can I determinate the reason off all this ?

Thanks!

Comment: 5-10min is not a normal amount of time for a server spinup. How is this being hosted, how big is the app, what do your logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Phusion Passenger application server, you might want to use `PassengerPreStart` directive.

From [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html):

> By default, Phusion Passenger does not start any application processes
>   until said web application is first accessed. The result is that the
>   first visitor of said web application might experience a small delay
>   as Phusion Passenger is starting the web application on demand. If
>   that is undesirable, then this directive can be used to pre-started
>   application processes during Apache startup.